# TextBox Char Length Limit

Tags: c#, wpf

I searched and didn't find anything that helps my problem. I want my textbox and passwordbox to have a 32 character limit. I tried `MaxLength="32"` but its gives me this error:

> The member "MaxLength" is not recognized or is not accessible.

What parameter should I use?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Thats only desing XAML :D I dont have any code..

Comment: Are you sure you're using a TextBox and not TextBlock?  A TextBlock does not support user input, so there is no max length on it.  However, a TextBox will have a max length property you can set.

Comment: Can you paste your xaml?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on WPF, and you are only using XAML as you said than there's no problem using MaxLength, this code makes that TextBox doesn't accept more than 5 chars input:

```
<Grid>
        <TextBox MaxLength="5"/>
</Grid>
```

if you still have any problem (that I/we can't imagine if you don't wanna post your code) with this, then just try Clean/Rebuild your project.